# searching word or phrase among files

Tags: java, optimization, search

I've written a program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author Mohammad Faisal
 */
public class FileContentMatcher {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String textToMatch = "Quick Styles gallery on";
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    String content;
    int found = 0;
    int notFound = 0;
    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };

    File path = new File("E:\\anchit\\temp");
    File[] listOfFiles = path.listFiles(filter);
    for (File file : listOfFiles) {
        content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        if (content.contains(textToMatch)) {
            //System.out.println("Found in: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            found++;
        } else {
            //System.out.println("No found\n" + content);
            notFound++;
        }
    }
    for (String pth : paths) {
        System.out.println(pth);
    }
    System.out.println("Found in " + found + " files.\nNot found in " + notFound + " files.");
}
}
```

In which I've used [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) api.
My actual requirement is to list all the files in the given directory which contains the search phrase `textToMatch` in minimum amount of time about 4-5 seconds, where number of files could be upto 100000. But this program takes much more time than that.
So I need to optimize this code but not getting **how**?
Is there any API which can help me? I've heard of `Lucene` but not getting how to work with it.

Comment: well, the number of files doesn't tell how many GB/TB of data you need to go through; and how many seconds does you program currently take?

Comment: With no constraints or control over the organization of data, you are unlikely to get those levels of performance. Opening some random file takes roughly 10 ms. 10^5 X 10^-2 secs ~ 15 mins. (Performance is known to be hard to predict, but do not expect to get anything less than several minutes without doing something different.) 

Consider also using full-text indexes.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca: well I've no idea of full-text indexes. How do it works?

Comment: [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) is the index&search Java library which I hear most about, but I've never used it. MS SQL Server (I've used its full-text indexes) (and probably other RDBMSs) ship with full-text indexing and search. There probably are simpler solutions probably but it totally depends on what your constraints are [Is mirroring the directory in Ramdisk and doing a grep an acceptable solution, where would we know?]. And that deep an analysis is beyond the scope of Code Review SE. You may try [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca: but as you can see in the program, I'm not using any RDBMS. I've to make search in `.txt` files

Comment: I would suggest you would, if you could ;) You should really try http://programmers.stackexchange.com for some other ideas; since your problem size, as @dnozay and I have pointed out, requires more than simple optimizations to achieve the performance you expect from common systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [poined out in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28490/searching-word-or-phrase-among-files#comment44734_28490), your current approach might be too slow for your goal of "about 4-5 seconds". Depending on what's your actual use case, using an index might indeed be a good idea. This is similar to how internet search engines do it.

To create the index:

- create a map `Map<String, List<File>>` for holding the association of search terms to files
- go through all your files, and for each word in each file, add that file to the list corresponding to that word in your index map
- you might want to skip common words, such as "a", "and", "the", etc., or you could even apply a [stemmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) to drastically reduce the variability in words

Once you've created the index (which could take quite some time), you just have to look up the search word in that index to get the list of files that contain the word (or a linguistic variant of it, if you used a stemmer).

As said before, the applicability of this approach depends heavily on your actual use case. If the files contain genetic sequences and you are searching a certain pattern, this probably won't help much. Even if you are searching for some complex phrase this might not work, as you'd have to add each possible (sub) phrase to the index. But if you are looking for individual words in ordinary text files (or HTML or the like) this might work.

*Update:* Since you seem to indeed search for complex phrases, you could try the following:

- create the index, as desribed above, optionally using a stemmer
- search for each word in your phrase (or the stemmed version thereof) in your index
- for each file that, according to your index, contains *all* the words, do a full-text search for the original phrase

Finally, if this still does not cut it, you could also create indexes for [word bigrams or even trigrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram).

Answer (score 1):

A few tips :

- Instead of reading the entire file into memory, use a `Reader`, reading only a small buffer at a time, to check for possible matches. This will improve memory usage, and avoid reading the entire file if the `textToMatch` is found.
- Separate the code that loops over the files, from the code that checks a file. Use multiple threads that check files. This is an ideal candidate for the [producer-consumer pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern) (using a blocking queue) with one producer, and multiple consumers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hitting a bottleneck in terms of sheer hardware, you may move to a distributed model using [`MapReduce`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). It works just like a distributed `awk` / `grep` conceptually. Enter big words like `Big Data`, which really is trading compute time on one machine (expensive one most of the time) with less compute time on more machines (commodity hardware most of the time) by following `divide-and-conquer` principles.

Here is a [link to a `Hadoop` tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html).

I wouldn't take this route unless you have identified that your solution is going to hit the limits. But consider this:

- what happens if your files grow over time?
- what happens if your have more files over time?

Distributed systems scale horizontally (number of machines) whereas a single machine does not scale well vertically (single machine specs ~ $$$).